# Insert two tables value to already exist tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables album_new and song_new. song_new table had column album_id, by this relation i can know which album has how many song. where album_id and song_id are auto-increment.

**album_new**

```
 album_id | album_name
    ---------+-----------
    1        | abs
    2        | def
```

**song_new**

```
 song_id | album_id | song_name
    1       | 1        | yahoo
    2       | 1        | lalala
    3       | 2        |kukukuku
```

when i insert the value of one table to another table like this

`INSERT INTO album(album_name) SELECT album_name FROM album_name`

the album_id changed and i can't insert song_new table table to song table. because the relation is inaccurate now. how can i insert these two table value to two another table album and song which had already some values. i can do this by server side code by using foreach loop but can i do it in sql? can any body provide me the syntax.

Edit: here are the two table where i want to insert the values of above tables

**Album**

```
 album_id | album_name
    ---------+-----------
    1        | aaa
    2        | bbb
```

**Song**

```
 song_id | album_id | song_name
    1       | 1        | old_song1
    2       | 2        | old_song2
    3       | 2        | old_song3
```

Comment: It si not a problem if the id of songs table goes out of order respect to the others songs of that album. You can recognize the album by the id, what's your problem?

Comment: i want to insert album to another table so if other table had already 5 albums and id of album 'abs' will be 6 and 'def' will be 7. and when i insert song table to another table. the yahoo song shows under wrong album

Comment: OK you can adding an offset to id equals to max of other table, i go to computer and write it as soon as possibile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already transferred your albums, you have to use the album name as a pivot..

```
Insert into song_new(album_id, song_name) (select a.album_id, c.song_name from song c join album b on b.album_id=c.album_id join album_new a on a.album_name=b.album_name)
```

In that situation you will have problems if there are plus that one album with the same name.
It was better to increment the id in album and in song table by the result of `select max(album_id) from album_new`and then transfer the entire tables in the new two with `insert into` and `select *`.

NEW
If you haven't.. Then is simple..

```
alter table album set id_album=id_album+(select max(id_album from album_new))
alter table song set id=album=id_album+(select max(id_album from album_new))
insert into album_new(select * from album)
insert into song_new(album_id, song_name) (select album_id, song_name from song)
```

Comment: thanks for help but no i didn't insert the album already and ablum name can be duplicate so i can't use album name as a pivot